# Can I know when will be the Kubernetes Cron Jobs beta/GA release?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Can someone please let us know the roadmap? I want to use Cron Jobs and get statistics features

Answer (score 0):

You can track this issue: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/41039 . This is about the topic `Migrate CronJobs to beta`

Comment: Can I know when the Kubernetes 1.8 will be released?